# Using the complex logarithm as a conformal mapping,

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I want to map the upper half plane, y>0, conformally onto the semi-infinite strip u>0, $-\pi < v < \pi$ in the w-plane.

I then studied the complex logarithm, and noticed that the principal branch, Log(z), maps every point z in $C - R^- \bigcup {0}$ to w = ln|z| + iArg(z), where Arg(z) ranges from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

So, the images of the whole plane, minus the negative real axis (and 0), have positive real part and imaginary part between $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

Is my work done?  Can I conclude that the mapping from the UHP to the semi-infinite strip is just $$w = Log(z)?$$

Something seems a little off, since *all* of C (minus the negative real axis) maps to the horizontal strip.

Thanks,

Comment: The upper half-plane maps to a certain strip. (The entire plane maps onto a larger strip). That real part is not positive. 
I didn't say you'd be done. Once you get straight what strip the logarithm maps the upper half-plane onto, figure out what _part_ of the upper half-plane maps onto _half_ that strip...

Comment: Hi @DavidC.Ullrich, so I think Log(z) maps the UHP to the infinite strip, 0<y<$\pi$, and Quadrant I maps to the bottom half, 0<y<$\pi/2$, while Quadrant II of the z-plane maps to the upper half of this strip.  Now I have to somehow make the strip semi-infinite and then cover $-\pi < y < \pi$

Comment: True, but not the "half strip" I was asking about - what you say here doesn't help. Say $S$ is the strip $0<y<\pi$. Say $U$ is the semi-strip defined by $0<y<\pi, x>0$. So Log maps the upper half-plane onto $S$. Now the question is this: Log maps exactly _what_ _part_ of the upper half-plane onto $U$?

Comment: Hmm... to have positive real part in the image, ln|z| must be positive, so |z| must be greater than 1.  This means Log maps everything in the UHP that's *outside* of the upper half of the unit disk.  This region maps to U, under the action of Log(z).  What next?  How can I handle the space inside of the upper half of the unit disk in the z-plane?  Also still need my semi strip to cover -pi < y < pi.  Thanks,

Comment: We're getting there. Absolutely right, Log maps the part of the upper half plane _outside_ the unit disk to the semi-infinite strip you want. Let's say $S$ is the set of $z$ in the upper half-plane with $|z|>1$.
Now the tricky part. Say $Q$ is the first quadrant and $\Pi^+$ is the upper half--plane. There exists a $\phi$ mapping $\Pi^+$ to itself that maps $Q$ to $S$. Hint: Saying $\phi$ maps $\Pi^+$ to itself says exactly that $\phi(z)=(az+b)/(cz+d)$ where $a,b,c,d$ are real and $ad-bc>0$. Hint: $S$ has "corners" at $1$ and $-1$, while $Q$ has "corners" at $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Hi, @DavidC.Ullrich - I was so close! I used your most recent comment, along with Professor Israel's hint and arrived at f(z) = $2 Log(\frac {-\sqrt(z) - 1}{\sqrt(z) -1}) $.  But the answer, at least what's posted by a student shows $2 Log(\frac {-\sqrt(z) - i}{\sqrt(z) -i}) $

Comment: The mappings z+1/z-1, z-1/z+1, z+i/z-i, and z-i/z+i are bothering me, I guess.  All four mappings look virtually identical, and I was very careful with the symmetry arguments in constructing my Mobius transformation and thought I had surely gotten the right one...

Comment: Thanks so much, Professor Ullrich, this was an exciting problem to work on for a couple of days.  I can't wait to think about another tricky conformal mapping problem...

Comment: (after I review some of the basics...)

Comment: Hooray! Yes, the square root takes the upper half place to that quadrant, a Mobius transformation takes the quadrant to what we called $S$, and then the logarithm finishes it. You getting a different answer from some other student proves nothing - there are infinitely many possible choices for the map from $Q$ to $S$ for example...

Comment: It was very, very exciting to arrive at an answer :-), @DavidC.Ullrich.  Can I just ask you one more question re: this problem?  I had rotated the space that you call "S" incorrectly by scaling with i, which would spin space by the desired 90 degrees, but *counterclockwise*, in the positive direction.  So I changed my answer to scale by -i, spinning the space 90 degrees *clockwise* to be in the right half-plane.  Then I can apply the *principal* logarithm without any issues - since the branch cut of Log (z) is along the negative real axis.  Is this ok?

Comment: Also, I was *just* going to ask about whether conformal mappings are unique, and you read my mind.  So, I'll have to be confident with my own final answers on these problems, since it's likely my answers will not match up with other student's final answers.  Thanks so much, Professor Ullrich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point in the UHP is $z=r e^{i\theta}$ with $r > 0$, $0 < \theta < \Pi$.  $w = \text{Log}(z)$ maps this to $w = \log(r) + i \theta = u + i v$ with $u = \log(r) \in (-\infty, \infty)$, $v = \theta \in (0,\pi)$. Note that the logarithm of a positive number could be negative. So you have the infinite strip, not a semi-infinite strip.

EDIT:

Hint: half-plane $\implies$ quarter-plane $\implies$ half-disk $\implies$ semi-infinite strip.

Comment: Hi Professor Israel, thanks so much for the clarification.  I currently have an infinite strip,   $0< v < \pi$, in the w-plane.  Can I please get another hint on how to proceed?  I need a semi-infinite strip, and then have it cover $-\pi < v < \pi$

Comment: Hi Professor Israel, I'd like to think that I was very close :(  my answer is f(z) = $2 Log(\frac {-\sqrt(z) - 1}{\sqrt(z) -1}) $, but I think it may be f(z) = $2 Log(\frac {-\sqrt(z) - i}{\sqrt(z) -i}) $ instead.  Thanks so much for your help.  I will start a new question on some basic mappings that are confusing me.

Comment: Hi @RobertIsrael, I just tried this problem again and am getting a slightly different answer.  When I get myself to the region in the upper half plane, outside of the unit disk, I had originally rotated this space 180 degrees, and applied the Log(z) map, and multiplied by 2.  But I think the rotation should only be 90 degrees - so that the target space is on the right half plane.  What do you think?  If this is correct, then I have my answer as 2Log($\frac{i\sqrt{z}-1}{\sqrt{z}-i})$

Comment: If $z$ is in the upper half plane, $\sqrt{z}$ is in the first quadrant, and $
\dfrac{i\sqrt{z}-1}{\sqrt{z}-i}$ is in the left half plane outside the unit circle.  You want to take a logarithm of that, but not the principal branch logarithm because you don't want a branch cut running through this region.

Comment: Oh, hmm...I realized I rotated counterclockwise (positive direction).  What if I rotated the region in the upper half plane, outside the unit circle, 90 degrees *clockwise* with the scalar -i?  Then my answer becomes $2Log(\frac{-i\sqrt{z} + 1}{\sqrt{z} - i})$, keeping the principal branch of log.  What do you think?  There should be no issues with the branch cut along the negative real axis now, @RobertIsrael.